# Page is not binding when angularjs version upgraded to 1.4.1 from 1.3.10

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-polyfill, core-js

I have upgraded my current version of angular to 1.4.1 and as a result, the page is not loading
I have a sample code to demo it.

```
'use strict';var app = angular.module('test').controller
('testcontroller', function () {
    return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function () {
        var vm = this;
        var car = {
            Name: "BMW",
            Price: "222"
        };
        vm.document = car;
    });
}
);
```

HTML page to render

```
<div ng-controller="testcontroller as vm">
<div>
    <p> {{vm.document.Name}}</p>
</div>
```

An empty page is showing after the upgrade.
it will not be throwing any console error.

**the code will work if I remove the regeneratorRuntime.wrap function, but I don't want to remove it.**

working js file

```
'use strict'; var app = angular.module('test').controller
('testcontroller', function () {
    var vm = this;
    var car = {
        Name: "BMW",
        Price: "222"
    };
    vm.document = car;
}
);
```

any solution is available to return the response using regenerator.wrap?

We are using babel-polyfil.js